How do I properly initialize and use attributes in Python classes?
I'm new to Python and am trying to understand how classes work. I've written a simple class, but I'm having trouble with initializing attributes and using them correctly. Here’s what I have so far:
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def introduce(self):
        print(f"Hi, my name is {self.name} and I am {self.age} years old.")

I want to understand:

Is this the correct way to initialize attributes in a class? Are there other best practices I should know about?
How do I create instances of this class? For example, if I want to create two people, John and Jane, how would I do that?
How can I access and modify attributes after creating an instance? If I want to change someone's name or age, how should I do it?

I created an instance of the Person class like this:
john = Person("John", 30)

This seems to work, and I can call john.introduce() to get the output I expect. However, I'm not sure if this is the best approach to initialize and access attributes. When I try to change the age attribute directly, like this:
john.age = 31

I want to understand if:

There's a better way to set or update attributes, like with specific methods or property decorators.
I'm following the best practices for initializing attributes and creating instances.
There are any recommended practices for modifying attribute values after instance creation, especially for larger projects.


You're off to a good start, but there are some issues and areas for improvement in your code and understanding. The correct way of writing is:
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def introduce(self):
        print(f"Hi, my name is {self.name} and I am {self.age} years old.")


How is this an improvement on the question as shown above?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
